# How to perform a computation using trigger event?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I created a form list update. And every row has a sets of textbox.
Each textbox has its own value based on my query result. And at the end of every column there is a selection box. And you can choose VALID or INVALID. My goal is simple, if the user select an INVALID status for each row. The value of the quantity and price and total will be set to 0 and the computation below will be decreased based on the the item/row that has been set to the selection. If INVALID, the selected row will be deducted to the subtotal amount.

**Problems:**

1. In triggering if the user set the status to INVALID I have no
   problem but if the user trigger the selection back to VALID. I can't
   get back again my value.
2. If the user set the to INVALID, there is no deduction of total in the subtotal. Becuase I don't know how to do that.

Here's a bit of my code below:

```
Here is my jquery section:

$('[id^=qty],[id^=price]').on('change',function() {

        var index = this.id.match(/\d+/)[0];
        var qty = parseInt($('#qty'+index).val());
        var price = parseFloat($('#price'+index).val());
        var total = 0;

        $('#total'+index).val((qty * price ? qty * price : 0).toFixed(2));

        var total = 0;
        $('[id^=total]').each(function(index){
            total+=parseFloat($(this).val()?$(this).val():0);
        });
        $('#sum_of_total').val(total.toFixed(2));

        var vatable = total / 1.12;
        var vatable_amt = vatable * 0.12;
        var totalVat = vatable + vatable_amt;

        $('#vatable').val(vatable.toFixed(2)); 
        $("#vatable_amount").val(vatable_amt.toFixed(2));
        $("#gtotal").val(totalVat.toFixed(2));

    });

    $('[id^=status_validate]').on('change',function(){

       var index = this.id.match(/\d+/)[0];

       var status_set = $("#status_validate"+index).val();
       var price_set = $("#price"+index).val();
       var qty_set = $("#qty"+index).val();
       var total_set = $("#total"+index).val();

       var temp_price = price_set;
       var temp_qty = qty_Set;
       var temp_total = tota_set;

       console.log(status_set);

       if(status_set == 'VALID'){

            $("#price"+index).val(price_set);
            $("#qty"+index).val(price_set);
            $("#total"+index).val(price_set);

       }else{

            price_set = 0.00;
            qty_set = 0.00;
            total_set = 0.00;

            $("#price"+index).val(price_set);
            $("#qty"+index).val(price_set);
            $("#total"+index).val(price_set);

       }

    });
```

And here is the loop part

```
$val = 0;

foreach($order_info_list->result_array() as $details){

    $val++;

    $vatable_input = $details['vatable_input'];
    $vatable_amount = $details['vatable_amount'];
    $total_amount_due = $details['total_amount_due'];

    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='itemdesc[]' value = ".$details['item_desc']." /></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='qty[]' value=".$details['item_qty']." id='qty{$val}' /></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='price[]' value=".number_format($details['item_price'],2)." id='price$val' /></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='total[]' class='k-textbox' id='total{$val}' style='font-family: courier; text-align: right; background-color: lightgray; color: red' readonly='readonly' value='".$details['total']."' /></td>";
        echo "<td width='30%'>";

         $stat = $details['status'];

         echo "<select name='status[]' id='status_validate[$val]'>";    
             if($stat == 'VALID'){
                echo "<option value='VALID' selected='selected'>VALID</option>";
                echo "<option value='INVALID'>INVALID</option>";
             }else{
                echo "<option value='VALID'>VALID</option>";
                echo "<option value='INVALID' selected='selected'>INVALID</option>";
             }
          echo "</select>";
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $idx = $details['poid'];

    echo "<input type='hidden' name='idx[]' value='{$idx}' />";

    $code_x = $details['order_code'];



}
```

Below is the displaying of total computaion

```
 <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td>VATable Amount:</td>
   <td><input type="text" class="k-textbox" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" style="color: red; text-align: right; font-family: courier" name="vatable" id="vatable" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td>VAT Input:</td>
   <td><input type="text" class="k-textbox" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" style="color: red; text-align: right; font-family: courier" name="vatable_amount" id="vatable_amount" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>TOTAL AMOUNT DUE:</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="k-textbox" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" style="color: red; text-align: right; font-family: courier" name="subtotal" id="gtotal" /></td>
  </tr>
```

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y6d8m/4

Comment: paste you code here http://jsfiddle.net/ and save it

Comment: Ok but i have database interaction.

Comment: Don't use `floats` for currency values. The loss of precision will affect your arithmetic. Use integer values in pence (or cents, or whatever) and reformat to two decimals when displaying.

Comment: oh ..!!! than you can't do it .

Comment: So i will change the parseFloat to parseInt?

Comment: Ok i will try to create a static data. An i will post it to jsfiddle

Comment: here's the fiddle guys http://jsfiddle.net/y6d8m/

Comment: updated fiddle jsfiddle.net/y6d8m/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When "INVALID" save the last data

```
        $("#price"+index).attr('data-last',price_set);
        $("#qty"+index).attr('data-last',qty_set);
        $("#total"+index).attr('data-last',total_set);
```

When user change back restore it

```
restoreLast($("#price"+index));
restoreLast($("#qty"+index));
restoreLast($("#total"+index));

function restoreLast(e){
    e.val(e.data('last'));
    //trigger automatic computation
    e.change();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y6d8m/3/

Comment: Yes sir, but i can do that. My problem is after triggering the selection back to original state I can't get back again my value. For example if i have a qty = 2 and price = 5 then total = 10 and the subtotal is 10 also. If the user set the selection to INVALID the qty will be set to 0 and price and subtotal as well. If i set to VALID again i will get back again my old values.

Comment: Ok it works but how can i do a computation based on the trigger event?

Comment: Ok i tried sir but the computation is not working. When i tried to trigger it.